# Call Webservice from timer job behind proxy

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to get external data from a web service calling from a sharepoint 2010 timer job.

If the call was to be made from a sharepoint application I would add something like this to the web.config file:

```
<proxy usesystemdefault="False" scriptLocation="http://location" bypassonlocal="True"  />
```

or

```
<proxy usesystemdefault="False" proxyaddress="proxyadress:port"  bypassonlocal="True"  />
```

And it was good to go.

The problem in this case is that I should not specify the proxy on the code and I should not make modifications to the web.config file.

Not being able to overcome this problem, I'm having an "Unable to connect to remote server" exception message when calling GetResponse from HttpWebRequest object.

Which are my options to overcome the issue?